# Is it now possible to use pagination in Instagram's sandbox mode?

Tags: pagination, instagram, instagram-api

With Instagram's new policy, is it possible to use the pagination in sandbox mode with `user/recent/media`?

Comment: not possible in sandbox, since media is limited to latest 20 media

Comment: Thanks for the answser.